# Calling UITable View Delegate Method

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm working with UITableView in UIViewController..I am using the following delegate methods.....

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Once I load the view I find all delegates has been called..... But I need to call these methods in a button click.....
I tried in this way....

```
[self tableView:table numberOfRowsInSection:rows];
[self tableView:table cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
```

I find that these methods has been called,but nothing happened (code inside these delegates doesn't works).... I don't knw why??? Any suggestions???

Comment: You're not supposed to call these delegate methods directly, you implement them so that the table view can call them to ask for the information it needs to display itself. Please define what "doesn't work" - what aren't you seeing that you expect to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the code inside the button click function it will call all the delegates of the tableview

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

or complete code to your solution is:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    customCell *cell = [[customCell alloc]init];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[customCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;


    NSArray *topLevelObjects=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (customCell *)[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];


    int count=0;
    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        count++;
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[customCell class]])
        {

            cell= (customCell *)currentObject;  

            UILabel *sName = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1]; 

            //Checking the flag that is set in the btnClicked event
            if (flag) {
                    sName.hidden=YES;
                }

                else{
                sName.text = [arrayResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];             
                }

        }
    }

    return cell;
    [topLevelObjects release];
    [cell release]; 

}

-(IBAction) btnClicked:(id) sender{
flag=YES;
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Try this it will work..

Comment: One more query.... Inside each cell of the table I ve a label..When I'm reloading the table all the labels are not removed... Hw can I remove all the label inside the click

Comment: I think you have a custom cell...before reloading the table apply a boolean flag=YES; and inside your cellAtRowAtIndexPath delegate of the uitableview check the flag if yes hide the label.

Comment: Itz cellForRowAtIndexPath rite??

Comment: i thnk tis won't work bcz if use the above logic label at the last cell ll hide and goes on to the first.. I ven't tried itz a guess